# Dynamically generated form submission and Spring framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a dynamically generated form (using jQuery). So beforehand I don't know how many form elements do I have. Does anybody have any idea how we can do it.?

Answer (score 0):

POST the fields in the request body as a JSON-ified map, and use Jackson to to turn it into a `Map<String, String>` on the controller side. Your controller method would look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/url", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public getMap(@RequestBody Map<String, String> fields){
    //Manipulate fields as you wish
    .
    .
    .
}
```

That way you will have your fields as key/pair values inside the map ready for you to manipulate them.

You can turn your fields into a map fairly easily using jQuery (or similar) like this:

```
var fields = {}
$.each("input:text", function(i, item){
    fields[mapKeyValue] = $(item).val();
}
```

This example assumes that your pair value is the text input, but you can manipulate the values however you want. This is by no means a complete example, but should give you an idea on how to start.